# difficult in runing the R code for ggtree

Tags: r, phylogeny, multiple-sequence-alignment, ggtree

I tried to run the below code but ended having issue. I have checked thoroughly  and I didn't find any mismatch in fasta sequence

```
tree = read.tree("phylotree.txt")

ggtree(tree, layout='circular') + 
   geom_tiplab(offset=4, align=TRUE) + xlim(NA, 12)
msaplot(tree, fasta ="phylotree.fasta", window=c(120, 200))
```

```
Error in msaplot(tree, fasta = "phylotree.fasta", window = c(120,
200)) :    taxa name in input sequences are not match with the ones on
the tree, please check your input files...
```